# Cannot change max_execution time in php ini - or how can one figure out where php ini settings are being changed, if not in main php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, php-7

I am asked by the developer of a Wordpress theme to change my `max_execution_time` to `180` instead of `60`, which is leading to some failures in the import script of an XML file.

I have changed my `php.ini` as specified by `phpinfo()`, but `max_execution_time` still returns `60` instead of the expected `180` that I have changed it to in php.ini.

The `phpinfo()` also specifies other `.ini` files being loaded, but I cannot seem to find any `max_execution_time` specifications within said files.

Is there any way to figure out where to find the aforementioned setting, if not in the main php.ini? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

The apache2 service has been restarted a couple of times, and I have even attempted to restart the server itself. No luck.

Comment: Is there something like `php_value max_execution_time 60` in the apache config or .htaccess, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @janh2 - I will check out my apache config

Comment: @janh2 no dice. There is nothing except from MaxKeepAliveRequests in Apache2 conf

Comment: Do you have `auto_prepend` load something in the php.ini by any chance? You're checking the phpinfo() outside of WP, right?

Comment: Yeah, @janh2 - created a file with `phpinfo()` in it: `Loaded Configuration File`:`/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to append `php_admin_value max_execution_time 300` to my VirtualHost file. For some reason, this did the trick. This should be considered a hack as far as I am aware, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file), maybe your apache2 is corrupted because already many people satisfy with this